# Is there any equivalent of `justify-content: end` for `display: grid`?

Tags: css, flexbox, css-grid

I wanted to align grid items to the right, so the left space would be empty but seems that there is no property which would make it possible.

```css
.container {
  border: 1px solid black;
  width: 400px;
}

.grid {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(4, 1fr);
}

.justify {
  justify-content: end;
}

.flex {
  display: flex;
}

.item {
  width: 100px;
  border: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<div class="container grid">
  <div class="item">1</div>
  <div class="item">2</div>
  <div class="item">3</div>
</div>

<div class="container grid justify">
  <div class="item">1</div>
  <div class="item">2</div>
  <div class="item">3</div>
</div>

<div class="container flex justify">
  <div class="item">1</div>
  <div class="item">2</div>
  <div class="item">3</div>
</div>
```

I want a constant number of columns, but a varying number of items and items should be aligned to the right.

```js
const grids = document.querySelectorAll('.grid')

addEventListener('click', () => {
  grids.forEach(grid => {
    const item = document.createElement('div')
    item.className = 'item'
    item.textContent = 'x'
    grid.appendChild(item)
  })
})
```

```css
.grid {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(5, 1fr);
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.mirror {
  transform: scaleX(-1);
}

.item {
  border: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
Click anywhere
<br> What I can do:
<div class="grid"></div>
What I want:
<div class="grid mirror"></div>
```

Comment: you don't have a left space but an empty column. Justify-content will work if you only had 3 columns and a left space

Comment: ex: https://jsfiddle.net/e6khp91q/

Comment: @TemaniAfif I don't understand your comment. Maybe I didn't clarify good enough. I want a constant number of columns, but a varying number of items and items should be aligned to the right.

Comment: you cannot with such configuration because you always have 4 columns and you place item inside them, you are missing one item but you still have 4 columns that you cannot align because they are taking all the space

Comment: I can't understand why I can do it to the left, but not to the right

Comment: you cannot do it to the left either, your item are simply placed from left to right. replace `1fr` with `auto` and see the difference. 1fr will give 4 full column so no empty space to align (remember that you are aligning the columns and not the items)

Comment: Added another example to clarify

Comment: I know that the space is caused by the lack of items. I just want this space to be on the left. `grid` is the only asymmetric property that I know of in CSS.

Comment: @TemaniAfif you were right I was wrong. Thanks for the explanation

Comment: you will always have one row? If it's the case we can have a specific solution

Answer (score 0):

You can alternate the direction to get what you want but you won't get the same order.

```js
const grids = document.querySelectorAll('.grid')

addEventListener('click', () => {
  grids.forEach(grid => {
    const item = document.createElement('div')
    item.className = 'item'
    item.textContent = 'test'
    grid.appendChild(item)
  })
})
```

```css
.grid {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(5, 1fr);
  border: 1px solid black;
  direction: rtl;
}

.item {
  border: 1px solid red;
  direction: ltr;
}
```

```html
Click anywhere
<br> What I can do:
<div class="grid"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just specify the column to start from:

```
.grid div:first-child{
  grid-column-start: 2;
  
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/GetafixIT/awf2v3Ls/